# COUNTIFS Multiple Criteria and ignoring blanks values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am currently making a data report for analytical study.

For context: It is a register of people's mental health issues. There are three columns of reasons for appointment. I want to make a table that counts the amount of people who have booked in for appointments based on criteria such as their "housing status".

I have managed to work for most of my sheets.

However, there is one report that looks at multiple column criteria that some of which are blank or different values in different columns. Which seems to return #VALUE instead of a count.

For example:
[image: #value example]

This is the formula I have so far, which worked when it was single column counting with multiple criteria, but now that it is checking multiple columns it returns #value.

```
=COUNTIFS(HousingSituation!$F:$F,A3,Register!P:R,B3)
```

I thought to check each column as an individual criterion but then it only counts if all three items are same.

Here is an example of the P:R range in my main register I have had to make this up for the example and data protection:

[image: P:R Range]

For this the resulting value I am looking in my count table would be:
[image: resulting count table]

As it is one person with each of those issues.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You have the 2nd criteria range set to multiple columns (P:R). You will need to adjust this formula to check only one column per criteria. You could create a helper column in Register if that's easier.

Comment: I have edited my original post to give a bit more context however some of the registered outcomes will have multiple values. If you look at my new edit, some might have both Anger management and Punctuality issues. so they need to be counted together.

Comment: Can you show sample of columns P:R and your desired output?

Comment: I have edited the post again with examples as you asked

Comment: Perhaps other ways to accomplish, but I believe this would work: `=COUNTIFS(Department!$F:$F,A3,Register!P:P,B3) + COUNTIFS(Department!$F:$F,A3,Register!Q:Q,B3) + COUNTIFS(Department!$F:$F,A3,Register!R:R,B3)`

Comment: This is what I tried before but sadly it then only confirms true and counts if all three reasons are the same.

Comment: I cannot replicate. It works for me, where I have different reasons and it correctly counts.

Comment: @Isolated if B3 is in both P and Q on the same row it will count that row twice.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, it would but I don't think the same reason would be listed twice. Based on the sample data, it looks like it should be distinct reasons. OP, would there be occasions where the Reason 1 is the same as Reason 2 for a user? Seems odd if that would ever happen.

Comment: Yup, I reread the comment and think they are thinking that is the same as: `=COUNTIFS(Department!$F:$F,A3,Register!P:P,B3,Register!Q:Q,B3,Register!R:R,B3)` which it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demoing the answer in the comments, where this works as long as you don't have the same reason repeated on the same row. If you do have the same reasons repeated on the same row, then a different solution is needed and I'll remove this answer.

Cell J2 formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(O:O,$H$2,P:P,I2) + COUNTIFS(O:O,$H$2,Q:Q,I2) + COUNTIFS(O:O,$H$2,R:R,I2)
```

[image]